# Perl how to provide full or absolute path to fcopy() function

Tags: perl, absolute-path

I am new to perl and want to write a basic program to copy the entire directory contents to another directory. My first hurdle is that I need to give the absolute path for source and destination and I can't seem to get the following code to do that:

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use File::Copy;
use File::Copy::Recursive qw(fcopy rcopy dircopy fmove rmove dirmove);

my $source_dir = "C:\\Tools\\MyTool\\Scripts";
my $destination_dir = "C:\\Tools\\MyTool\\Scripts_Copy";

fcopy($source_dir,$destination_dir) or die $!;
```

When I execute this, I get the error that the "No such file or directory"

Comment: You need to use forward slashes instead of backslashes.

Comment: Thanks. I did try the same with forward slashes as well like : my $source_dir = 'C:/Tools/MyTool/Scripts";
my $destination_dir = "C:/Tools/MyTool/Scripts_Copy";
but still no luck

Comment: You are using `fcopy`which is for copying *files*. I suggest using `rcopy`instead. The latter function uses `dircopy`or `fcopy`depending on whether it has to copy a file or a directory. 
For detailed description see http://search.cpan.org/~dmuey/File-Copy-Recursive-0.38/Recursive.pm

Comment: Thank you. Using rcopy was the right way indeed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fcopy` is only for copying *files*, `dircopy` for copying directories.
Use `rcopy` which decides to use the appropriate function, depending on whether it has to copy a file or a directory.

For a detailed description, please refer to the [CPAN documentation of File::Copy::Recursive](http://search.cpan.org/~dmuey/File-Copy-Recursive-0.38/Recursive.pm).